# Template Specialization Failing in C++ / CLI

Tags: templates, c++-cli

I have the following class in C++/CLI:

```
namespace Example
{
    class c1 {};
    class c2 {};

    public ref class ExampleClass
    {
    public:
        template<typename T> 
        static int StaticIntFunction()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        template<> 
        static int StaticIntFunction<System::String>()
        {
            return 1;
        }

        template<> 
        static int StaticIntFunction<System::Int32>()
        {
            return 2;
        }

        template<> 
        static int StaticIntFunction<Example::c1>()
        {
            return 3;
        }

        template<> 
        static int StaticIntFunction<Example::c2>()
        {
            return 4;
        }

        template<typename T> 
        static System::Type^ StaticTypeFunction()
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        template<> 
        static System::Type^ StaticTypeFunction<System::String>()
        {
            return System::String::typeid;
        }

        template<> 
        static System::Type^ StaticTypeFunction<System::Int32>()
        {
            return System::Int32::typeid;
        }

        template<> 
        static System::Type^ StaticTypeFunction<Example::c2>()
        {
            return Example::c2::typeid;
        }

        template<> 
        static System::Type^ StaticTypeFunction<Example::c1>()
        {
            return Example::c1::typeid;
        }
    };
}
```

And I call all of the functions:

```
System::Type^ t1 = Example::ExampleClass::StaticTypeFunction<float>();
System::Type^ t2 = Example::ExampleClass::StaticTypeFunction<int>();
System::Type^ t3 = Example::ExampleClass::StaticTypeFunction<System::String>();
System::Type^ t4 = Example::ExampleClass::StaticTypeFunction<Example::c1>();
System::Type^ t5 = Example::ExampleClass::StaticTypeFunction<Example::c2>();


int i1 = Example::ExampleClass::StaticIntFunction<float>();
int i2 = Example::ExampleClass::StaticIntFunction<int>();
int i3 = Example::ExampleClass::StaticIntFunction<System::String>();
int i4 = Example::ExampleClass::StaticIntFunction<Example::c1>();
int i5 = Example::ExampleClass::StaticIntFunction<Example::c2>();
```

My problem is that while all of the `StaticIntFunction` correctly resolve and execute their template specialization, the specialized `StaticTypeFunctions` all use the same method - the last method declared in the class.  In the above example that would be `StaticTypeFunction<Example::c1>()` but if I re-order them it's always the last method.

That is,

```
i1 == 0
i2 == 2
i3 == 1
i4 == 3
i5 == 4
```

but

```
t1 == null
t2 == t3 == t4 == t5 == Example::c1::typeid
```

All of the `t` variables should have unique values; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get from `template<typename T> static System::Type^ StaticTypeFunction() { return T::typeid; }`?

Comment: Using your source code and VS2012, everything is behaving as you expect. Different values for the 5 t variables.

Comment: @JoelRondeau I was hoping that something was wrong with my syntax or the Type^.  What's weird is that if I copy and paste the code to another part of my project it *does* work.  Is there a compiler switch or something in Visual Studio that could help me see something more low-level?

Comment: @BenVoigt The general template works as expected (if I remove the C1 specialization, I correctly get the default template function).  My problem seems to be only with creating specializations.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've determined that this code runs properly when copied to a different file, but doesn't run properly the way that it is, it becomes a problem of finding out why this version of identical code isn't behaving properly.

When I've had a similar thing happen, there are two things I typically do:

1. Max out the warning level of the compiler. In this case, that is done via switch `/W4`.
2. Start commenting things out of the code until I have something that works or I just find the problem.

In this case, I'd comment out the working code (`StaticIntFunction`), comment out all but 2 or 3 cases of the broken code (keep the template, the string and the int). Then start looking at everything before that code (#include, other code not shown here).

I've also found that because I write a lot more C# code than C++/CLI code, I look for problems with semicolons. I just know that for me, I'll miss required semicolons in C++/CLI code because I'm often thinking in C# and translating.